# Mongoose : How to update all documents in a collection with todays date as field value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection with a field called "dueDate" A function from the frontend regularly sends the current date. This date data is used as a criterion for updating. unfortunately, I get an empty array when I run the function.

here is the controller :

```
exports.UpdateComplainStatus = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { date } = req.params;

  Employee.updateMany(
    { dueDate: new ISODate(date) },
    { $set: { complainStatus: 'good' } }
  ).exec((err, pool) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console. log('due date updated successfully...');
      res.send(pool);
    }
  });
});
```

and here is the Schema;

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const EmployeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
complainStatus:{
  type:String,
  required:false,
  default:'good'
},
complainDetail:{
  type:String,
  required:false,
},


dueDate:{
  type:Date,
  required:false,

},
  attendances: {}
    
   
},{timestamps:true});

const Employee=mongoose.model("Employee", EmployeeSchema,'employee001');

module.exports=Employee
```

here is what I want to achieve:
1.Filter only document with endDate : "with today's date"
2.Update the complainStatus field (e.g. from suspension to good)

Comment: Your schema doesn't have any `endDate` field.

Comment: sorry, its actually  dueDate on the original code,I have corrected the question

Comment: What's the problem with existing code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Mongoose` `exec` function takes in a callback as a parameter.
You should try this:

```
exports.UpdateComplainStatus = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { date } = req.params;
  try {
   const response = await Employee.updateMany(
    { dueDate: new ISODate(date) },
    { $set: { complainStatus: 'good' } }
   ).exec();
   console.log(response); <-- This won't be an array of updated documents. 
   const updatedDocs = await Employee.find(
    { dueDate: new ISODate(date) }
   ).exec();
   res.send(updatedDocs);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

The `updateMany` will return the count of objects matched, updated, etc. as mentioned in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-updateMany). To return the updated documents themselves as the API response. You will have to fetch them again using `find`.